# How many times can one do a Sec. 1031 exchange, with the same capital?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, like-kind-exchange

I was given advice that if I wish to purchase another apartment, best to do a Sec. 1031 exchange with the one I own now. I might only want to live there for a few years. Can I do the Sec. 1031 exchange again to defer paying capital gains taxes in the future? If so, how or what are the conditions?

Note: We used to live in it until 5 years ago. We rented it for 5 years. It is still rented out. Now we want to sell and buy a place to live in.

Comment: "I might only want to live there for a few years" is this an investment property that you rent out ? Or is it a place you live? Or is a multi-family building that you live in one unit and rent the rest?

Comment: We used to live in it until 5 years ago. We rented it for 5 years. It is still rented out. Now we want to sell and buy a place to live in.

Comment: Can you move back into it for the qualification period? (not sure what it is, 6 months? 1 year?)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do a Sec. 1031 exchange to buy a residence. Sec. 1031 is for *like-kind* exchanges, and rental exchanged into a residence is not a like-kind.

Comment: Ok. What if it was a residence, what would be the answer?

Comment: @MrMonee 1031 is for investments, not for personal property (residence). For primary residence you can use Sec. 121 exclusion.